# Can't write in c:\ disk with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a scheduled task to create a file in the s:\ disk from an other user. The operator user can't access the disk, but the save user can read and write in the s:\ disk. I wrote my script and created the scheduled task, but it wasn't working.
Recap, creating a scheduled task with the operator user to execute a script creating a file in the s:\ disk.
After realising it wasn't working, I tried breaking down the problem into steps. First I tried executing the powershell script with the operator user. The script is the following:

[image]

So I tried creating the file in the C:\ disk, but it wasn't working. I tried changing all the directories to C:\Users\operator\Documents, and then it worked. If I open Windows PowerShell ISE as administrator and run the script, it works just fine when the directories are C:\

So my questions are:

- Why can I create the file in C:\Users\operator\Documents but not in C:\
- Why do I have the run as administrator for it to work if operator is already the admin ?
- Would the reason why my scheduled task is not working the same as why I can't write in c:\ ?

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code/errors/data _unless there is no other way to convey the needed info._ why? lookee ... Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I was in a virtual machine and couldn't copy the code. Thought it was ok tu put image

Comment: Why not use the **%TEMP%** folder: **`"$env:Temp\configuration.reg"`** or **`Join-Path $env:Temp configuration.reg`**?

Answer (score 1):

When you install windows, The C:\ location has TrustedInstaller as owner, so you need administrative permissions to write in the folder. You will have rights to create folders, but to write a file, you need admin permissions. You can manually fix this, but its not recommended to do this. Instead, it is recommended to create a folder in the root of C and use that instead.

Comment: I work as LPChip has suggested and it is trouble-free for me.

Comment: But I tried creating the file in C:\Program Files (x86)

Comment: You can use Program Data - that works well. But trying to write directly to Program Files or Windows usually leads to issues. Work with neutral folders.

Comment: Program Files is another folder like the C:\ location. It has Trusted Installer as owner and no write permissions for regular users. Requires administrative access to work with this. Program Data can be used, or you can create your own folder in C:\ and use that.